# Can you use comma in "I am not dumb, I am smart."?

Tags: punctuation, commas, run-on-sentences

Is it a comma splice. I feel like the sentence has a sort of repetition to it, so a comma could be used. I don't know. It is like saying "I don't like to read, I don't like to write, and I just don't like English as a whole".

Comment: It's a comma splice. But in modern english, it's not a big problem though.

Comment: Since the sentences are short, it's OK to use a comma there. However, because there's a contrast between the sentences, I'd opt for a semi-colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comma splices are stylistic errors only when the clauses are long. Two short clauses such as you have can be joined by commas without any problem.

> Strunk & White notes that splices are sometimes acceptable when the clauses are short and alike in form, such as:
>
> *The gate swung apart, the bridge fell, the portcullis was drawn up.*
>
> The famous sentence *I came, I saw, I conquered* falls into the same category.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)

It would be beneficial to note that the criteria "short" and "alike in form" are met in your example.